# Пропустить слеши в регулярном выражении, пока не найдётся определённая строка

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

Недавно я экспериментировал с regex. Тестировал на [этом сайте](https://regex101.com), потом на Python. У меня есть следующее выражение:

```
^(Resources\/)*
```

Вот мои строки:

```
Resources/
Resources/hello
Resources/test
Resources/Resources/abc123
Resources/Hello
Resources/Resources/Resources/sup.txt
Resources/mods/Resources/Unknown.test/test.txt
```

Ожидаемый вывод:

```
Resources/
Resources/hello
Resources/test
Resources/abc123
Resources/Hello
Resources/sup.txt
Resources/mods/Unknown.test/test.txt
```

Полученный вывод:

```
Resources/
Resources/hello
Resources/test
Resources/Resources/abc123
Resources/Hello
Resources/Resources/Resources/sup.txt
Resources/mods/Resources/Unknown.test/test.txt
```

Я также пробовал изменять выражение:
`^(Resources\/)*`
Но результат был тот же самый.
Вот мой код Python:

```py
from re import sub as regexsub
# ...
class ...:
    resfold_nosep = 'Resources'
    sep = '/'
    # ...
    def ...(...):
        # ...
        path = ...
        regexsub("({}{}){2,}".format(self.resfold_nosep, sep), "", path, 1)
```

Мой вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы в строках заменялись все случаи появления **Resources/**?

Comment: Зачем `re.sub` обозначать как `regexsub`?

Comment: Формировать регулярное выражение из переменных - опасная практика. Пользуйтесь литералами пока можете.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Я обозначаю `re.sub` как `regexsub` потому что считаю это более понятным и удобным, чем просто `sub`. Можно перепутать `sub` с "**substract**" (вычитанием).

Comment: `re.sub(r'(?<!^)Resources/', '', text)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```py
import re


lst = '''
Resources/
Resources/hello
Resources/test
Resources/Resources/abc123
Resources/Hello
Resources/Resources/Resources/sup.txt
Resources/mods/Resources/Unknown.test/test.txt
'''.split()

for s in lst:
    print(re.sub('/Resources', '', s), '<-', s)
```

> ```
> Resources/ <- Resources/
> Resources/hello <- Resources/hello
> Resources/test <- Resources/test
> Resources/abc123 <- Resources/Resources/abc123
> Resources/Hello <- Resources/Hello
> Resources/sup.txt <- Resources/Resources/Resources/sup.txt
> Resources/mods/Unknown.test/test.txt <- Resources/mods/Resources/Unknown.test/test.txt
> ```

**P.S.** [Namerek](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/397399/namerek) в комментарии правильно говорит что регулярное выражание не нужно. Достаточно простой замены:

```py
for s in lst:
    print(s.replace('/Resources', ''), '<-', s)
```

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь работает.

Comment: Прекрасный вариант решения, тем более с таким паттерном и `re` не нужен. `'source_text'.replace('/Resources', '')` даст такой-же результат

Answer (score 1):

Без `regex`, как будто бы удобнее, но тут дело вкуса)

```py
arr = ['Resources/',
       'Resources/Hello',
       'Resources/Resources/abc123',
       'Resources/Resources/Resources/sup.txt',
       'Resources/mods/Resources/Unknown.test/test.txt',]
for path in arr:
    path = 'Resources/' + ''.join(path.split('Resources/'))
    print(path)
```

Вывод:

```
Resources/
Resources/Hello
Resources/abc123
Resources/sup.txt
Resources/mods/Unknown.test/test.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

text = """Resources/
Resources/hello
Resources/test
Resources/Resources/abc123
Resources/Hello
Resources/Resources/Resources/sup.txt
Resources/mods/Resources/Unknown.test/test.txt"""

print(
    re.sub(r'(?<!^)Resources/', '', text, flags=re.M)
)
```

---

```
Resources/
Resources/hello
Resources/test
Resources/abc123
Resources/Hello
Resources/sup.txt
Resources/mods/Unknown.test/test.txt
```